# Swing - timer not firing event at the inteval

Tags: java, swing, events, timer, actionlistener

I'm making a program that, for the time being, just prints `Printing...` every half second. Here is my code:

```
package mainPackage;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Ticker {

    public static void tick() {
        System.out.println("Printing...");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        ActionListener timerListener = new ActionListener(){

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            {
                tick();
            }
        };

        Timer mainTimer = new Timer(500,timerListener);
        mainTimer.start();
    }
}
```

From my understanding the `mainTimer` object should be firing the event handled by `timerListener` every 500ms. When I execute this code nothing happens, am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out to me. Now that I have corrected this error, is it possible you could tell me what your answer was?

Comment: `SwingTimer` works on EDT. You do not get an event from it because your application thread is terminated before EDT enters an event handler. To work, you need to sleep the main thread at least until the first event (say 600 ms).

Comment: See my posted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use swing timer under swing [event dispatch thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html):

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    ActionListener timerListener = new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            tick();
        }
    };

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Timer mainTimer = new Timer(500,timerListener);
            mainTimer.start();
        }
    });
}
```

If you don't plan on changing the GUI from the timer, consider using [java.util.Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html)

Comment: Your explanation needs expanding - why would the user need to perform this operation this way?  Why did there code fail?